# Blender Multiple Bake Problem

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-baking, baking, error

When I try to bake multiple textures blender don't merge all textures

What I want to make
https://imgur.com/a/n3hbiSw

and this is what is happening
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Blender Bake Problem](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/174361/blender-bake-problem)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to bake three objects on one UV Map texture by doing the following:

- In UV Image Editor, create a new image texture. I did a simple black 1024x1024.
- Select all three objects. Tab into Edit Mode. Unwrap "Light Map Pack" for quick and dirty testing. You will see the unwrap of all three objects evenly distributed across the UV image.
- Create materials for your objects.
- Add a "Image Texture" node to each object material (but do not connect it to anything). Make sure the Image Texture node has the UV map you created for baking in it. You should see "3" users for that Image Texture node. Make sure that node is selected / highlighted in each object.
- Select your objects and hit bake.

Comment: Almost same thign what i did 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MH7Xdol5erw
i did everything same

Comment: And it still does not work? I would recommend getting the latest stable release of Blender if you have not already.

Comment: tried 2.83 and 2.82 but no

Comment: Have you tried saving the UV texture bake image? Maybe try CPU render instead of GPU? Could there be conflicting add-ons enabled?

Comment: dont have any addons i tried gpu also cpu too

Comment: also after bake blender ruin original texture ( image )

Comment: You want to send me a blend file so I can look?

Comment: https://we.tl/t-ztlaZJViYb